# lse_xsens_mti error ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Linux: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bits
ROS: fuerte
Intel core 2 duo E8400
device: Xsens MTi-G-28A53G35
```

I have some troubles with this package:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_xsens_mti

I have to install some dependencies like gps_commons and cereal_port. When I resolve the dependencies, I do rosmake and the package is installed with 0 problems.

I launch with xsensDriver.launch and everything seems to work very well but not is this case, the topics are publishing at good rate but all empty.

I get all values 0.

I don't know what I must do from here.

Any Ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67957/lse_xsens_mti-error-ubuntu-12.04/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, the problem is the configuration of synchronism mode in the device.

If one program configure the device in synchronism mode, this pkg publish only 0 in all topics.

I wonder if there are some way to change the sync mode to async mode with this pkg.

Somebody?

---

Originally posted by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) with karma: 330 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0